# grails run-app launches application but application not running when war deployed in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7

I am having a grails application that uses **grails 2.1.0**, **groovy 1.8.6**. When I run "grails run-app" the application starts and I am able to see the app running in my browser, but when I create war by "grails war", and deploy it in the webapp directory of my Tomcat 7, then the app doesnot run.
Before I run these commands, I always set my **JAVA_HOME** and **path** accordingly for **Java 6**. The application is an old one and is based on **Java 6**.

After deploying the war and starting the tomcat, when I check the application doesnot seem to run. When I check the log **localhost.2019-07-05.log** it gives me below error :

```
Jul 05, 2019 1:01:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 05, 2019 1:01:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 05, 2019 1:01:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry
    ... 9 more

Jul 05, 2019 1:01:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 05, 2019 1:01:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 05, 2019 1:01:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@4f9b20dd')
Jul 05, 2019 1:01:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@5a93f728')
```

I have also tried creating the war by setting env to development( **grails -Dgrails.env=development war** ) as suggested in a stackopverflow post, but no luck. I get same error.

Comment: Does it still fail after you restarted tomcat?

Comment: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/NoClassDefFoundError-java-util-HashMap-Entry-with-Java-8-td5720093.html perhaps its incompatible - as in what it was compiled in and what it is running in  actual issue and much about it out there is ` 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry` as per your logs above, althought that don't answer manual way of starting it -  have come across old sites I worked on where it would launch fine for dev but not to run as war - due to issues in the app - so maybe take a step at a time with a new app if it is moderately small to work with